Conditional Probability for Painted Cubes
I'm trying to work through a problem that has been asked before, but the answer that seems intuitive to me doesn't match the accepted solution.
The problem:
Suppose you are given a white cube that is broken into 27
pieces. This cube was originally 3
units by 3
units, and has been broken into 27
smaller cubes, with each smaller cube having dimensions 1×1×1
. Before this cube was broken, all 6
of its faces were painted green. You randomly pick a small cube and see that 5
faces are white. What is the probability that the bottom face is also white?
My reasoning for this problem is that there are only 7 cubes which have at least 5 white sides, namely the center cube (which wouldn't have been painted) and the six cubes at the center of each side of the bigger cube (which would have only one side painted). Given that we already know we are in the sample space of cubes which have at least five white sides, there is only one which would satisfy the hidden side also being white, namely the center cube. This would yield a probability of $\frac{1}{7}$.
However, the correct answer to this problem is $\frac{1}{2}$.
What mistake am I making in how I frame the problem?

here is a duplicate which provides an interpretation yielding the $\frac 12$  result.  Should say: I think the phrasing of the problem is very ambiguous.  The $\frac 12$ result emerges if you select a small cube uniformly at random, select a face from it uniformly at random, and then examine the other $5$ faces and note that they are all white.  That's a perfectly sensible mechanism, but it really needs to be spelled out.  It's not exactly intuitive.

To stress:  the mechanism you propose is different.  You select a cube uniformly at random and then ask an oracle "are at least $5$ faces white?" and receive the answer "yes".  Again, perfectly well defined, but hardly the same mechanism.  As you remark, this mechanism yields a different result than the other.

Extending the first comment of @lulu, in the first mechanism, if you select any of the $~6~$ cubes with exactly $~1~$ red face, you have a probability of $~1/6~$ that the selected face will be red, which will be true if and only if the other 5 faces are white.  So, by conditional probability, the overall computation is $$\frac{1/7}{\left[ ~1/7 ~\right] + \left[ ~6/7 \times 1/6 ~\right]} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

@user2661923 Yes, this is the content of the answer I provided...

@BenjaminDickman Good point.  However, the original poster might well have first examined lulu's comments, before getting to your answer.  In that event, the original poster might well have been confused about lulu's first comment, because the original poster had not yet read your answer.

I suspect the difference in framing is that the problem is saying, you pick a cube. Next, you check the sides one after another. The first five that you check are all white. What is the probability that the final side is white, too?
Note that this is different from saying, you pick a cube and can see that five of its six sides are white (etc). Under that interpretation, you would be correct with an answer of $1/7$.
Under the interpretation that I've suggested: The chance of picking the all white cube and seeing five consecutive white faces is $(1/7)\cdot1^5 = 1/7$. The chance of picking a five white one green cube and seeing five consecutive white faces is $(6/7)(1/6) = 1/7$, where the $1/6$ factor comes from the green face showing up as one of the six inspected; in particular, for this situation to have arisen, it would need to be the last face seen (which happens $1/6$ of the time).
You are locked into one of these scenarios, each of which arose with probability $1/7$; so, the chance you are in one (or the other) is, zooming out, $1/2$.

Could you clarify the first argument--i.e., how exactly has the sampling occurred such that the requested conditional probability is $1/2$?  I ask only because it is not quite clear to me and can't think of a situation for which it would be $1/2$.

@heropup Sure! Check the updated part and let me know if it's unclear.

I get it now:  the idea is that we are also incorporating the probability that the five faces that were inspected were also randomly chosen out of the six, hence the prior observation that they are all white increases the posterior probability that it is the all-white cube.

So this is more of a comment rather than an answer, but I think a useful way to conceptualize the different interpretations is to consider the following two experiments:
Experiment A:

An experimenter takes one of the 27 cubes uniformly at random without you seeing it.
The experimenter inspects the cube and places it on a table; if it has a green face, that face is placed table side down so that you cannot see it.
You are able to see the five exposed faces and you see that they are all white.

Experiment B:

An experimenter takes one of the 27 cubes uniformly at random without you seeing it.
The experimenter places the cube on the table in a random orientation.
You are able to see the five exposed faces and you see they are all white.

Then clearly, the two experiments are not equivalent.  Given that the five exposed faces are white, the experimenter must have chosen one of the $7$ cubes that have at most one green face, with equal probability.  But in the second step of the experiment, the experimenter (A) may or (B) may not choose which face is obscured--when it is, then all $7$ of those outcomes are represented when you see the cube in Step 3.  But when it is not, only those outcomes for which the cube was all white, or there was a green face and by random chance it was oriented table side down, are represented when you see the cube in Step 3.  In such a situation, the obscured face is equally likely to be white or green because there are six orientations of the all-white cube that are observable, but only one orientation of the cubes with one green face that are observable.
As already noted, this difference is not at all clearly expressed in the wording of the problem.
